Issue accessing a sub element
I've got an application that manages real estate transactions, amongst other things.  When an offer comes in basic information is collected; buyers name, selling agent name, email, phone, etc. . .  If the offer is accepted I've a button that converts the offer to a transaction,  Once it's a transaction this is what the transaction tab looks like.

On he right , the middle button with the label "Return to Offers" is the issue.
The HTML:
    <section class="transaction-tools">
        <div>
            Cancel Transaction
        </div>
        <div id="return-offer">Return to Offers</div>
        <div class="confirm-remove">
            <div data-offer-id="# offerID  #" id="confirm-move-back">CONFIRM</div>
            <div id="cancel-move-back">CANCEL</div>
        </div>    
        <div>Mark as Closed</div>
    </section>  

div#return-offer is a switch that slides open the div.confirm-remove container which reveals the inner divs that control the confirm and cancel divs.
The JS:
//THIS IS THE CONTAINER
const existing_transaction = document.querySelector(".transaction")


const t_tools = existing_transaction !== null 
      ? existing_transaction.querySelector(".transaction-tools")
      : null

The section.existing_transaction does not always exist, thus the funky variable assignment to t_tools.
In my testing environment I know that there is an existing transaction.  Accessing the childNodes of t_tools hasn't been an issue either. See below:
if( t_tools )
{    
    step1 = t_tools.querySelector("#return-offer")
    _confirm = t_tools.querySelector(".confirm-remove #confirm-move-back")
    _cancel = t_tools.querySelector(".confirm-remove #cancel-move-back")
}

I can console.log the above variables and get a solid hit.  The individuals elements are accurately being targeted.  Where I'm having issues is when I try to assign an event listener, like so:
//MODIFIED CODE

if( t_tools )
{    
    t_tools.querySelector("#return-offer").addEventListener("click", openMoveToOptions)
    t_tools.querySelector(".confirm-remove #confirm-move-back").addEventListener("click", moveToOffers)
    t_tools.querySelector(".confirm-remove #cancel-move-back").addEventListener("click", closeMoveToOptions)
}

The functions assigned the click events have a an alert("Yay") set so that I know the click is registering, but it is not.  I've also used the Firefox dev tools to inspect the elements and there is no event assigned.
What I'm trying to figure out is why the events are registering.  I've done this type of pattern so often for assigning events I just don't get why it's not working.
If someone has an idea as to how I might diagnose this issue, it would be great.
I've done a search of the entire root directory of the web app to see if I have other elements that are named the same and there is not.
I've tried different ways to assign the event.
element.onclick = (e)=> theFunctionToUse()
element.onclick = (e)=> {theFunctionToUse() }
element.onclick = function(e) { theFunctionToUse() }
element.addEventListener("click", theFunctionToUse)

You know the stuff you start to do when you can't figure out why the heck it's not working.
Thanks in advance.
